# Java ASN.1 Parser - how to decode information against defined structure

Tags: asn.1, cdr

I try to do a simple asn1 parser using bouncy castle library. I got 3 files - 2 scheme (or sequnce) and BAR file. Firstly i try to read a schema from files and next to use BER file to decrypt.

CDR-HLR.asn :

```
CDR-HLR-Version3 DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN
EXPORTS
CDR-HLR-VERSION3
;

IMPORTS
Timestamp,
IMSI,
CdrType,
ISDN-AddressString 
FROM DataTypes
;


CDR-HLR-VERSION3 ::= 
SEQUENCE {
timestamp  Timestamp,
type       CdrType,
msisdn  [0] ISDN-AddressString OPTIONAL,
imsi    [1] IMSI,
vlr     [2] ISDN-AddressString
}
END
```

DataTypes.txt

```
DataTypes DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN

EXPORTS
AddressString,
ISDN-AddressString,
Timestamp,
IMSI,
CdrType
;

AddressString        ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..maxAddressLength))
ISDN-AddressString   ::= AddressString (SIZE (1..maxISDN-AddressLength))
Timestamp   ::= OCTET STRING
IMSI        ::= TBCDSTRING (SIZE (3..8))
CdrType ::= ENUMERATED {updateLocation(2), cancelLocation(3)}

END
```

And next i want to read/encode BER file by loaded schema.

testcdr.ber:

```
   031512907038000€48790005968260060018293827‚1
```

I cant find any simple example for read objects by scheme/sequence. Can somebody tell me how to start?

Comment: Done ! Thanks for tip mate

Comment: Much better. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Did you just print the binary BER encoding as text? The Euro sign and the comma are strange. You need to provide the content in hex.

Comment: i got content in hex, what next?

Comment: I was hoping you would post it here so that we can see an example of what you are trying to parse.

Comment: testcdr.ber - hex : MDMEDTE1MTI5MDcwMzgwMDAKAQKACzQ4NzkwMDA1OTY4gQ8yNjAwNjAwMTgyOTM4MjeCATE=